# boost::geometry::index::rtree get intersection area of boxes from rtree::query

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, geometry

I'm having boost::geometry::index::rtree of a boost::geometry::model::box. With  rtree::query I'm getting all boxes that intersects with the set one. Now I need to calculate the intersection square for all the returned boxes. I can write the code that will do it, but probably in boost there is already something that do this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`boost::geometry::intersection`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersection/intersection_3.html) will do it.